# Is it correct to say "Translation of over 50 documents in various topics."?

Tags: usage

So, I work as a trasnlating documents from one language to another.
And, I want to say I have translated over 50 documents in various topics in a bullet list

Is this correct? "Translation of over 50 documents" sounds very awkward.

"Translation of over 50 documents in various topics."?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't say "translated" instead of "translation of"?

In business writing, these sentence fragments are used when there is an implied common beginning. If this is your resume, the bulleted list could be understood to start with "I have", i.e. "I have translated...". I this were a job description, it would state something more like "The job requires..." and then you would have tasks like "translation of documents" or "organization of customer records".